# I want users browsing from an iPhone to have the option to upload only a video or an image, not both

Tags: ios, iphone, forms, ios7, mobile-safari

I have two forms on a website.

- One requires that a user upload a video
- The second requires that a user upload an image

When a user clicks the button to attach a file to the form, the user is always given the two options:

- "Take Photo or Video"
- "Choose Existing" - the user could select any file type they choose

---

Vimeo restricted this file attachment feature somehow to be restricted to just enable video uploads (in the past, they seem to have limited their mobile functionality recently).  A user would see the following two options:

- "Take Video"
- "Choose Existing" - the user could only select video files

---

How can I make the user only able to select files of the appropriate file type when attaching a file to a form?

Comment: Are you able to playback that video which you uploaded , back on iphone safari browser ?

Comment: This isn't a forum for asking questions in response to someone else's question.  Yes, I am able to playback video on an iPhone to a user using Safari, but there are many things involved in ensuring that functionality.  Try asking elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restrict the media types that a file `input` will take, you can use the [**`accept`**](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#attr-input-accept) attribute.

For images only:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

For video only:

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*">
```